# Carrierwave is not sizing versions using rmagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rmagick

I am trying to use carrierwave to manage images. My problem is that all versions of the images I upload are created, but at the full size. Code:

```
class TechnologyImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  #process :scale => [100, 100]

  version :small do
     process :resize_to_fit => [25,25]
  end
  version :medium do
     process :resize_to_fit => [50,50]
  end
end
```

All image versions are displayed as the size of the original upload.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you fix yours? Would be super grateful if you could share the solution. thanks

Comment: Hi there, same here. I mean if I specify only 1 version it works correct, but when multiple versions are present it generates still just one version. This could be some version bug maybe? o.O

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you guys have this issue because of the same cause as I, but maybe.
I needed to move the uploaded files to a private folder, witch I'm sure you did as well.

After my upload I wanted to delete the cache what I did with:

```
after :store, delete_cache

def delete_cache( new_file )
  FileUtils.rm_rf %{#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/uploads}
end
```

The problem with this, is that after a version is created, the after :store will be triggered, so the app removes the cache directory, so the other version methods couldn't read that file anymore.

For me a temporal solution was to move the cache_dir to a private folder. What I need to empty later in a different way, that i'll need to figure out, so:

```
def cache_dir
  %{#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/uploads}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem was that the rails environment was named 'staging' on the server and 'development' on the mac.

Line 4 at file config/initializers/carrierwave.rb (line 4) disables the carrierwave processing for environments named 'staging'.

In order to make the processing work, I needed to enable with this line:

```
config.enable_processing = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I have  a somehow similar problem with my app.
Though i think i figured out that, when using versions,
it is helpful to set every 'process' as a version...
Otherwise i've noticed that some methods were 'overwriting' others...
Bizarre.

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  if Rails.env == "production"
    storage :aws
  else
    storage :file
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  #this is the 'first' process, 'while you upload', the one that seems to be an issue
  process resize_to_fill: [228, 250]


  version :industry do
    process resize_to_fit: [228, 250]
  end

  version :portrait do
    process resize_to_fill: [360, 200]
  end

  version :modal do
    process resize_to_fill: [330, 300]
  end

end
```

---

which would then become ::

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  if Rails.env == "production"
    storage :aws
  else
    storage :file
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  #i put everything as a version and it sorts the problem out..

  version :base do
    process resize_to_fill: [228, 250]
  end

  version :industry do
    process resize_to_fit: [228, 250]
  end

  version :portrait do
    process resize_to_fill: [360, 200]
  end

  version :modal do
    process resize_to_fill: [330, 300]
  end

end
```

I hope this is 'true' and will be useful to other users

Marin